# I set up email alerts in event viewer for 4624. How do I turn them off now?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, eventviewer

My inbox is now flooded with alerts as someone added a share that is causing 4624's to be fired every few seconds.  I thought I set up the alert under the event viewer. but I don't see where or how to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task scheduler.

Drill down through Task Scheduler Library then to Event Viewer Tasks.